# How to get the value of an exported variable in the console

Tags: command-line, environment-variables

If I wrote

```
export COMP_WORDS="this words"
```

I need something like

```
get-exported COMP_WORDS
```

expecting something like

```
COMP_WORDS="this words"
```

I tried

```
set | grep COMP_WORDS
```

but it takes others lines

Comment: what's wrong with `echo $COMP_WORDS`?

Comment: It is perfect. I don't thought in that posibility

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To get the value of VARIABLE you can use

```
echo $VARIABLE
```

The quotes don't survive though

```
$ COMP_WORDS="you said what?"
$ echo $COMP_WORDS
you said what?
```

Unless you quote them...

```
$ quote='"2b || !2b"'
$ echo $quote
"2b || !2b"
```

It makes no difference whether you set the variable yourself or not

Answer (score 7):

You can use `printenv`:

```
$ export var=foo
$ printenv var
foo
```

In alternative to `echo` you can also use `printf`.

```
printf "%s\n" $COMP_WORDS
```

Comment: With `printf` you should do `printf "%s\n" "$COMP_WORDS"`, so that the variable's contents are not interpreted as a format string.

Answer (score 4):

In bash, if you want output that's reusable setting the variable again, you can try `declare`:

```
$ declare -p USER
declare -x USER="muru"
$ export foo='abc
> def
> hij"
> '"'"
$ declare -p foo
declare -x foo="abc
def
hij\"
'"
```